# Accessing CIImage bytes, crashes app

Tags: ios, bitmap, ciimage

I'm porting some OSX code to iOS and need to access the bytes of a CIImage. The OSX version does this with a NSBitmapImageRep, but on iOS i need to jump trough some hoops.

Here is the code i'm trying to run

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);

CGRect extent = [image extent];
//png.Load((UInt8*)CFDataGetBytePtr(data), extent.size.width, extent.size.height, true);

CFRelease(data);
//CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

It works as expected, but after a while the app crashes. I have no idea why. I'm taking a guess at memory leak / out of bounds memory. As far as i can tell everything is being freed correctly... If i comment those lines out, nothing crashes. If i comment CGDataProviderRelease back in the app crashes almost immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to CFRelease(cgImage) - you used "create" to create it no?

Comment: I feel dumb. That was a problem. CFRelease(cgImage) makes the app a lot more stable, but i'm still crashing (But it takes twice as long to crash now). I don't know if there is anything else in there i may be missing...

Comment: Run the project using Instruments, Leaks and Object Alloc. You will probably find one type of info that is leaking. Its not all that hard to use.

Comment: Thanks dave! I'm knee deep in Instruments now. I think i can take it from here.

Comment: @SebastianGreifeneder so he solved it by finding and correcting all memory management issues - do the same.

Comment: However, I'm using the Apple UIImageEffects class now: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h.html
works like a charm!